# R - readHTMLTable: Failed to load external entity

Tags: r

I'm trying to follow a fellas blog on how to get NHL Data on R.
This is the start of it and it's where I'm having trouble.

```
library(XML)
tables <- readHTMLTable("http://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2016_games.html")
unlist(lapply(tables, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
```

Once I run that, I'm getting the error

```
Error: failed to load external entity "http://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2016_games.html").
```

I've tried the work arounds using httr/Rcurl, and it works until I get upto the bit of his tutorial where it says I need to input

```
for (i in c(2010:2015)) {
readHTMLTable(paste0("http://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_", i, 
    "_games.html"))
regular <- tables[["games"]]
playoff <- tables[["games_playoffs"]]
message(" Saving...", "\r", appendLF = FALSE)
write.csv(regular, file = paste0("./", i - 1, i, ".csv"))
write.csv(playoff, file = paste0("./", i - 1, i, "Playoffs.csv"))
Sys.sleep(20)
```

}

I'm attempting to do the for-loop for different seasons but obviously I'm getting the original error and don't know how to bypass that with httr/Rcurl etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's `readHTMLTable`, in the first call to it you have an uppercase `R`. And I tried your link in Firefox, it seems that it is `https` not `http`.

Comment: thanks @RuiBarradas, it was just a typo on the page. Not one that I'd made on the actual code, and it is indeed https, but all of the sister websites for other sports are https aswell, but i've tried them all with what i'm wanting to do with NHL and they work fine.